# Как исправить ошибку Unity Editor

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Я создал новый пустой проект, затем добавил в него FirebaseAuth и FirebaseDatabase, написал скрипты на регистрацию и обмену данными, добавил меню, и нажал Play чтобы проверить, при загрузке вылезла вот эта ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после Unity Editor просто закрылся и не сохранился, но если удалить скрипты регистрации и обмены данными всё работает! Мне нужно как-то исправить эту ошибку, ото я не могу из-за этого продолжить над созданием своего проекта, помогите пожалуйста как исправить, чтобы она не вылазила при нажатии на Play!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Загляние в логи https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039118331-I-have-been-asked-to-provide-a-log-file-where-do-I-find-this

Comment: А что нужно делать с этим файлом (info-log.json)??